# Jquery Autocomplete URL Based On Selected Value From Another Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a form allowing users to submit timesheets. This consists of multiple table rows for each day of the week. Each row is created by a call to AddRow, which adds the HTML, and also adds an autocomplete box on the JobNumber field, so the user can look up and select the required job.

I now need to add a second autocomplete to the Description field to allow the user to pick tasks that have been created for that job. I therefore need to pass a parameter in the source URL specifying the job that was selected in the previous box.

However, when I try to find the value of Job, it always returns "undefined".

What am I missing?

Here's the a simplified version of what I have:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

function AddRow(day) {

    var count = 1;

    var availableTags = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"];

    var row = "<tr>" +
        "<td>&nbsp;</td>" +
        "<td>" +
            "<input type='text' style='width:100px' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].JobNumber' name='" + day + "[" + count + "].JobNumber'>" +
            "<input type='hidden' style='width:100px' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].JobID' name='" + day + "[" + count + "].JobID'>" +
        "</td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' size='50' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].Description' name='" + day + "[" + count + "].Description' class='Description' data-day='" + day + "' /></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' size='6' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].Start' name='" + day + "[" + count + "].Start' class='numbersOnly' /></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' size='6' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].Finish' name='" + day + "[" + count + "].Finish' class='numbersOnly' /></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' size='6' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].Travel' name='" + day + "[" + count + "].Travel' class='numbersOnly' /></td>" +
        "<td>" +
            "<input type='hidden' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].Hrs' name='" + day + "[" + count + "].Hrs' class='Hrs'  />" +
            "<input type='text' size='6' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].Hours' name='" + day + "[" + count + "].Hours' class='Hours numbersOnly'  />" +
            "<select name='" + day + "[" + count + "].Mins'>" +
                "<option value='0'>0</option>" +
                "<option value='25'>0.25</option>" +
                "<option value='5'>0.5</option>" +
                "<option value='75'>0.75</option>" +
            "</select>" +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    $("#Table_" + day).append(row);

    $("input[id$='JobNumber']").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("input[id$='JobID']", $(this).parent().parent()).val(ui.item.JobID);
        },
        change: function(ev, ui) {
            if (!ui.item)
                $(this).val("");
        }
    });

    $("input[id$='Description']").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            // get the selected job number
            var jobID = $("input[id$='JobNumber']", $(this).parent().parent()).val();

            alert(jobID);

            if (request.term.length > 2) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Tasks/AJAXGetByJobNumber/" + jobID,
                    data: { Task: request.term },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        temp = $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.label,
                                value: item.value,
                                JobID: item.JobID
                            }
                        });
                        temp.unshift({ label: "Non-Chargeable Work", value: "Non-Chargeable Work", JobID: null });
                        response(temp);
                    }
                });
            }
        },
    });

}


</script>

<table id="Table_Monday">

</table>

<a href="#" onclick="AddRow('Monday')"/>Add</a>
```

I added an alert in there to check the value, but its returning "undefined" every time. I've tried JobID and JobNumber fields, neither of which work.

Comment: I'm not sure what this doing $(this).closest("tr").val(). Is this looking in the right place for the value?

Comment: @Tokn It's a typo. There's supposed to be an extra parens in there, like in the alert

Comment: No, I mean, it looks like you're trying to get the value of the closest 'tr' element. Is that correct?

Comment: Ah ok hang on. Typo. Yeh. LEt me take another look

Comment: @Gavin The code posted looks ok (other than typo-s which I'm assuming got in while copying it to SO, otherwise you'd get syntax errors). Could you make a MCVE?

Comment: What's an MCVE? Yea, they're just typos (i'd changed it to parent().parent() and changed it back to paste here without trying it first)

Comment: An example reproducing the error: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @blgt it's a magic link, next time just type `[mcve]` you get [mcve]

Comment: @blgt I've now added a full code sample that should work if pasted into an html file. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: `$(this)` matches nothing, replace it with `$(this.element)`

---

This is happening because `source` is a widget option, not an event. As such, it's (pseudo-)handler is not bound on the node instance

ie. Inside the `source` function, `this` references the widget, not the element, which results in the selector not matching anything

To access the element, simply use `this.element`:

```
var jobID = $("input[id$='JobNumber']", $(this.element).parent().parent()).val();
```

Here's a fiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/uxpeytxn/

NOTE: this is only relevant to `source`, in `select`, `change` and the other event handlers, `this` references the element, as one would expect

Comment: excellent, working now. I had a feeling it was going to be something like that.